# Install NuGet Package sans multi-language support

Tags: c#, nuget, multilingual

I have a nuget package that I use frequently (ClosedXML) and it installs multilanguage support.  This is a very large number of files that I don't need and don't want.  Is there a way to install nuget packages without this support?

Comment: There's nothing inherent in NuGet that provides that functionality, AFAIK. You'd be better off asking the package maintainers if they provide a package without the localization support.

Comment: Take a look at a similar [convo](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/386) on this issue in another major nuget package. Long story short, the advantages of doing this far outweigh the negative from the developer's point of view, so they won't bother. This package maintainer recommends to ignore it but you can also try a post-build step to manually delete them. This [ms article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages) can also offer perspective on why package devs do this

Comment: If this is for Excel interop and workbook/spreadsheet operations, you can also consider another library. I personally liked EPPlus more than ClosedXML, and it does not come with localization resources